# WebView iframe ignores frameborder="0"

Tags: android, html, android-layout, youtube, android-webview

I use webview to display youtube content.
For some reason, it adds a frame to the video.

Does anyone knows how to remove it?

My code is:

```
String data_html = "<iframe width=\"300\" height=\"162\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed
/RbyBj-pmNwM\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>";
video.loadData(data_html, "text/html", null);
```

And here is an example of the white frame I can't get rid of:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was to use a fully constructed html page:

```
String data_html = "<!DOCTYPE HTML> <html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xmlns:og=\"http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/\" xmlns:fb=\"http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml\"> <head></head> <body style=\"margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0;\"> <iframe width=\"300\" height=\"162\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/RbyBj-pmNwM\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe> </body> </html> ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you could try:

```
frameborder=\"0\" framespacing=\"0\"
```

Comment: Can you use CSS? If you can try like this: iframe { border:none }

Comment: Or try this also: frameborder=\"0\" border=\"0\"